# Train Pnet of mtcnn, the bounding box regression acc is very low! How to increase it? or is my lebal wrong?

Tags: regression, face-detection, bounding-box, faster-rcnn

I use the FDDB face pic to train the mtcnn for face detection. In the pnet, for bounding box regression, the acc stay around the 60%. Is there something wrong?

Epoch 397/400
1200/1200 [==============================] - 0s 131us/sample - loss: 0.5068 - conv4_1_loss: 5.4316e-06 - conv4_2_loss: 0.5052 - conv4_1_accuracy: 1.0000 - conv4_2_accuracy: 0.5850
Epoch 398/400
1200/1200 [==============================] - 0s 131us/sample - loss: 0.4350 - conv4_1_loss: 3.8598e-06 - conv4_2_loss: 0.4358 - conv4_1_accuracy: 1.0000 - conv4_2_accuracy: 0.5950
Epoch 399/400
1200/1200 [==============================] - 0s 131us/sample - loss: 0.8905 - conv4_1_loss: 5.0222e-06 - conv4_2_loss: 0.8863 - conv4_1_accuracy: 1.0000 - conv4_2_accuracy: 0.5817
Epoch 400/400
1200/1200 [==============================] - 0s 124us/sample - loss: 1.8505 - conv4_1_loss: 3.0373e-04 - conv4_2_loss: 1.8358 - conv4_1_accuracy: 1.0000 - conv4_2_accuracy: 0.5817

```
class P_Net(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(P_Net, self).__init__(name="P_Net")
        # Define layers here.
        self.conv1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(10, (3, 3), name="conv1")
        self.prelu1 = keras.layers.PReLU(tf.constant_initializer(0.25), shared_axes=[1, 2], name="prelu1")
        self.pool1 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="pool1")
        self.conv2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), name="conv2")
        self.prelu2 = keras.layers.PReLU(tf.constant_initializer(0.25), shared_axes=[1, 2], name="prelu2")
        self.conv3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), name="conv3")
        self.prelu3 = keras.layers.PReLU(tf.constant_initializer(0.25), shared_axes=[1, 2], name="prelu3")
        self.cls_output = keras.layers.Conv2D(2, (1, 1), activation="softmax", name="conv4_1")
        self.bbox_pred = keras.layers.Conv2D(4, (1, 1), name="conv4_2")
        #self.landmark_pred = keras.layers.Conv2D(10, (1, 1), name="conv4_3")

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Define your forward pass here,
        # using layers you previously defined (in `__init__`).
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.prelu1(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.prelu2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.prelu3(x)
        return [self.cls_output(x), self.bbox_pred(x)]#, self.landmark_pred(x)]

    def get_summary(self, input_shape): 
        inputs = keras.Input(input_shape)
        model = keras.Model(inputs, self.call(inputs))
        return model
```

For the bounding box lebal, in the Positive train_set ,i use the markable x1,y1 x2,y2 which the FDDB data supplied, just resize them depends scale of pic. is it wrong?
the Negative train_set, i set box lebal [0,0,0,0]

like this:
['./pos/20020816bigimg_932.jpg',
 1,
 ['0.2857142857142857',
  '2.2857142857142856',
  '12.285714285714286',
  '14.285714285714286']]